# Why the answer is not negative here?

Tags: percentages

If one number is $80\%$ of the other and $4$ times the sum of their squares is $656$, then What are the numbers?

My answer is -

let the two numbers be x and y.

$x = \frac 45 y$

$4(x^2 + y^2) = 656$

$\implies x^2 + y^2 = 164$

Now substitute $x =\frac 45 y$:

\begin{align}
&\implies \frac{16}{25}y^2 + y^2 = 164\\
&\implies \frac{41}{25}y^2 = 164 \\
&\implies y^2 = 100
\end{align}
therefore $y$ can be $10$ or $-10$.

and $x$ can be the $8$ or $-8$.

However, the answer given is $8$, and $10$. My doubt is the answer should be
$8,10$ and $-8$,$-10$. Am I correct here?

Comment: If no other condition is required on solutions, then both $\{8,10\}$ and $\{-8,-10\}$ are good.

Comment: Both are correct solutions but in real life situations, the negative solutions may be meaningless.

Comment: They both work. Perhaps there were more conditions?

Comment: No, this was the entire question. Also, If you see, I have asked the question on the percentages can be positive or negative in maths stack exchange. I got the answer as - percentages can be positive as well as negative. Another question, why I am down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if there are no other conditions, {8,10} and {-8,-10} are both valid answers. As for percentages being negative, a percent symbol just means divide by 100. So -125.658% is valid and so is 3^(1/2)%